# Just added new graphics card, now no video output at all

Tags: installation, video, graphics-card, graphics

So I just got a new graphics card, Palit Nvidia GT630 to be exact. Just put it into my computer. Booted it up. No graphics, doesn't even flash up BIOS.

So I put my old graphics card back in, doesn't work either. No video.

Any ideas?

I'm running a machine with an Ubuntu Partition and a Windows 8 partition, but i don't see how that would affect it since now BIOS doesn't even show up.

Comment: Forgetting to plug in power cables to your graphics cards? Didn't plug your cards into your monitor? My guess is its some face-palm answer. Does your motherboard have an integrated graphics chip you can try?

Comment: i think you have problem with the integrated graphics chip.

Comment: neither of my graphics cards require extra power cables. And nothing in my rig changed from before putting in the new card and now.

But just to be safe I unplugged everything, re-plugged everything back in still doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure your computer is actually booting?  Do you have SSH or VNC set up (assuming Ubuntu is the default boot) in order to remote in?

Comment: So what happens when you press the power button? Do the fans spin up? Does it beep?

Answer (score 1):

Tear the build down, and put it all back together again.  Double and triple check everything.  It could be an issue with a stick of Ram isn't sitting in the slot correctly, even though you *swear* that you didn't touch the Ram... or brush against it.

Check everything.  Check how the motherboard is sitting on the stand-offs.  Check every power connection.  Check how the heat sink is sitting on the processor, and check to make sure the processor is sitting in the socket properly.

Why?

Because you don't have another machine to test any of the parts with, and presumably you don't have another power supply to test with this machine... and you don't have a PSU tester, or a Ram tester, etc... so all you really can do is break it all down, and be methodical in making sure that it all comes back together properly.

Now, before you just take it all apart, and put it all back together in frustration... stagger the build.  Put the BARE MINIMUM that you need back into a working state, to check to make sure that just those components.  That means Motherboard, CPU, Heatsink, one stick of Ram, and a power supply.  No other cards.  No hard drives, no optical drives... just the bare minimum to show something on the screen.

Comment: 90% of the time, something isn't plugged in.  No matter how much experience you have or how many builds you've done.

Comment: @ChimneyImp and that's why you break it all down and triple check everything again, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.  I was strongly agreeing with you, sorry if that's didn't come out right.